# How could Delegate's target be the Delegate itself?

Tags: .net, clr

Researching a crash dump, I've encountered a perfect dead-end. A delegate with `target` field pointing to itself.

```
0:000> !do 00000027ce9395f8
Name:        System.EventHandler
MethodTable: 000007fb86cd5268
EEClass:     000007fb86ce2040
Size:        64(0x40) bytes
File:        ...mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fb867e5fa0  400002d        8        System.Object  0 instance 00000027ce9395f8 _target
000007fb867e5fa0  400002e       10        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _methodBase
000007fb86832290  400002f       18        System.IntPtr  1 instance       1ff71a0ae0 _methodPtr
000007fb86832290  4000030       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance      7fc24f737a8 _methodPtrAux
000007fb867e5fa0  4000031       28        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _invocationList
000007fb86832290  4000032       30        System.IntPtr  1 instance                0 _invocationCount
```

I assume there is no anything dramatically wrong. Following `_methodptr` I've located a static method.

Why `_target` is not null then? What is the logic of such behaviour?

Comment: This is perfectly normal.  Just try it with a little test program, the debugger can show you that _target isn't null.  Only the Target property getter returns null, it does so when _methodPtrAux isn't null.  Don't get stuck on this, it is not the problem you're trying to find.

Comment: @HansPassant I was somehow sure that target must be null, and this recursion came out of the blue.. I was just not ready :) As I checked briefly Delegate class code, target is always not null, and _methodPrtAux contains different information depending on call method. Is that just for fields economy?

Comment: Basically.  Under the hood, there are 7 different delegate types.  They use the available fields in different and non-intuitive ways.  They squeezed the delegate object size as hard as they could.